# `org-mode` doesn't align column bars properly

Tags: org-mode, org-table

When I make tables in org-mode, if the column value in the next row is longer, after pressing TAB, the new vertical alignment of "|" gets a bit distorted. This used to work fine before, it also works fine when I launch Emacs with `emacs -q`. Not sure what caused the problem, but I installed `avy`, `swiper`, `swiper-helm` and I've updated the system (I am on Fedora 27), but something messed things up. I've tried moving .emacs.d and to another folder leaving it empty, clearing .emacs and re-installing Emacs and `org-mode` only, it didn't help. Anyone had a similar problem? I saw some posts about the font type, but I am using the same font as before.

[image]

Comment: When I use `-q` option, supposedly emacs doesn't load the .emacs file and the alignment of the table bars works fine. But if delete both .emacs and .emacs.d then install `org-mode` and try to make a table the alignment doesn't work. What else is not loaded when emacs opens with `-q` flag?

Comment: I guess, `org-mode` internally also reacts to `-q` flag.

Comment: When you say you install `org-mode`, that makes us wonder whether the built-in version of `org-mode` that ships with Emacs works well when starting Emacs with the `-q` flag.  And, it also makes us wonder whether you are downloading a newer version of `org-mode` that does not ship with Emacs.  Try to narrow down the problem to the built-in `org-mode` without any user configuration; or, a newer version of `org-mode` without any user configuration.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I should have checked the versions, I thought `-q` just picks up the same `org-mode` in .emacs.d/elpa. I am on Emacs 25.3.1, the `-q` uses `org-mode` version 8.2.10, whereas I have installed 9.1.5 from "org" repository. Also, if I revisit the file, the bars get aligned properly.

Comment: I have the same issue, the last days - GNU Emacs 25.3.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2017-09-12 - Org mode version 9.1.5 (9.1.5-1-gb3ddb0-elpa @ /home/psnc/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20171225/) - Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/org/)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  The hard part about being a new participant on StackExchange is that you need to have a certain level of reputation / experience points to post a *comment*.  Inasmuch as your *answer* is actually a *comment*, you may need to wait a little bit of time to gain some more reputation / experience points.  You may wish to consider deleting the *answer* which is actually a *comment*; or else a moderator will probably do it for you.  [FYI:  I am not the person who down-voted without taking the time to leave some constructive criticism.]

Comment: This seems to be a bug introduced by commit f4ae1941 "Improve bidirectional reordering in tables" from 2017-12-23. This was reverted by commit 40189098 on 2017-12-28 and so the fixed version should be available from ELPA already.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10453)

Comment: I am experiencing the same - or something very similar -- with org 9.2. It's not by any means a show stopper, but it gives a slight feel of shoddiness that is a shame when I like org so much.

Answer (score 2):

The bug seems to have been fixed: `org-mode` version `9.1.5-10`, 2018-01-02 from org seems to align the bars properly. I also have the following in my .emacs file:
`(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)`

Comment: Please note that the Org Elpa domain protocol has changed from `http` to `https` at the beginning of this year.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution :

Removed

- Org mode version 9.1.5 (9.1.5-1-gb3ddb0-elpa @ /home/psnc/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20171225/)

and use

- Org-mode build in version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/org/)

Comment: I am not that bothered with the way the table looks when I type it in (I don't type in many tables) and since the alignment is restored with C-x C-v, I thought I will stick with 9.1.5. I've seen in another post people complaining about this so maybe someone experienced will look into it.

Comment: That seems a bit too radical to me: you can downgrade to a pre-9.1.5 release without going back all the way to 8.2.10. Of course, you may be happy with 8.2.10 (after all, it is what's distributed with currently released emacs), but the fact that you installed 9.1.5 presumably means you wanted a more modern version. It is very likely that this bug will be fixed in the next weekly release from ELPA - assuming it is brought to the attention of the devs. The best way to do that is `M-x org-submit-bug-report` to send the report to the mailing list.

Comment: I am fairly new to Emacs, I really just started diving into it from last week, I discover some really cool stuff every day :). I had no idea Emacs came with `org-mode` that's why I installed it. I did submit the bug report yesterday with `(org-submit-bug-report)`.

Comment: As other user has reported, you can upgrade to 9.1.6 now (Jan 25, 2018) available on Org Elpa. That contains the fix for this issue.

Comment: Version 9.1.13 also does not align properly

Comment: 9.1.9 also doesn't

Answer (score 0):

My org-mode table columns were not lining up because I was not using a *fixed-width* font. After switching to one of the *mono* fonts, they aligned.